# java: what is the total time complexity of two 0(n) and the time complexity of a Stringbuilder constructor sending in a string

Tags: java, constructor, complexity-theory, big-o, stringbuilder

an example would be two for loops not within each other. does it still equal 0(n). also why im asking questions time complexity of a Stringbuilder constructor sending in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StringBuilder` internally uses native `arraycopy(Object, int, Object, int, int)` at constructor call and append method call, which I think is much efficient than `2 for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

O(n) + O(n) = O(n + n) = O(n). In fact, O(k * n) = O(n) for any (finite) constant k.

But for practical programming issues, O(n) considerations are usually much less important than the coefficients involved. An O(n) algorithm with a large coefficient may be much worse in practice than an O(2<sup>n</sup>) algorithm with a tiny coefficient.

It would be much better to post your code alternatives, along with an estimate of the size of the problem, and ask which is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Question unclear.

But if you meant, two O(n) codes one after the other, then its still O(n).

```
Lim (2*n/n) = 2 (constant).
n->INF
```

Hence O(N) is both upper & lower bound implying `theta(N) => O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

**Time complexity question**:

Saying that an algorithm is O(n) means that that algorithm takes at most n*k steps, where n is the input size and k is *any constant*. So it doesn't matter if an algorithm takes n steps, 2n steps, (1/2)n steps, 100n steps, or 1000000n steps, it's still O(n).

So if you have two O(n) algorithms, they'll each have some constant k that gives the number of steps they take with respect to n: say, k1*n and k2*n. If you run both algorithms, the number of steps it will take is:

k1*n + k2*n

That is the same as:

(k1 + k2)*n

...since n is a common factor. And since neither k1 nor k2 grow with n (because they are constants) their *sum* k1 + k2 will not grow with n. That means that k1 + k2 is still a constant, so the runtime is still a constant multiples by n.

**Stringbuilder question**:

I don't know, but if I were you I would try running the constructor with increasing string lengths and see how long it takes each time. You can tell what the complexity is by how quickly the constructor slows down when strings get larger.